# Version of iterated expectations conditioned on subsets: Simple proof?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

Thanks for any help with this. It is from the Stokey and Lucas (1988) Recursive Methods text (pg. 208) and uses notation from a Dynamic Modeling course taught at Carnegie Mellon and at Florida International University.

How do I sketch a detailed proof with the joint and conditional PDFs to show the following "general" version of the law of iterated expectations?

Let $I_t$ denote information available at time $t$ where $I_t \in I$. And let $\omega \subset I$ be a subset of the original information set. Then the expectation of a random variable, $x$ conditional on the realization $I_t \in I$ is denoted $E[x|I_t]$. The law of iterated expectations is

$$E[E[x|I_t]|\omega_t] = E[x | \omega_t]$$

The furthest I can get is:

$$\sum^{I_t} E[x|I_t] f(I_t|\omega_t) = \sum^{I_t}\sum^x x f(x|I_t)f(I_t|\omega_t) = \sum^{I_t}\sum^x x \frac{f(x,I_t)}{f(I_t)}\frac{f(I_t,\omega_t)}{f(\omega_t)}= ?$$

It's difficult to see how you end up with $f(x,\omega_t)$ (which you'd need to obtain $f(x|\omega_t)$) from the last term. It seems to come down to whether it's true that $f(I_t,\omega_t) = f(I_t)$ when $\omega \in I$.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is $f$? You use it but give no definition.

Comment: This is common notation for a probability density function. A PDF is what is used in computing an expected value.

Comment: You are misusing notations big time--so much so that you lose yourself in the computations afterwards. Let me suggest to start by avoiding the confusion between random variables and the values they can take (and it is quite nice to have been reminded what PDFs are for...).

Comment: I'm not sure how the notation is being misused. A lower case f is used for PDFs while upper case F is for CDFs. This is commonly accepted notation. You're welcome.

Comment: @Did, I appreciate your attempt at answering, but some of your comments are just plainly incorrect. This comment on notation highlights my point. See [the obvious reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)

Comment: Read better: first your random variables are discrete hence there is no PDF, only PMFs. Next, if $X$ is a random variable with PMF $p_X$, then $p_X(X)$ is a random variable but you seem to use routinely $p_X(X)$ for $p_X(u)$ where $u$ is a value taken by $X$. And what is $f(I_t\mid\omega_t)$ even supposed to mean? And so on. Does the obvious reference contain even once something like $f(I_t,\omega_t)$, $f$ PMF, $I_t$ sigma-algebra, $\omega_t$ event)? (Linking to a page for definitions is good, *reading it* is better.) // "some of your comments are just plainly incorrect" Really? Give only one.

Comment: Well, it seems we are (stealthily) progressing, sort of... Now, $I_t$ is an event and $\omega_t$ a sigma-algebra, apparently. Unfortunately, then $E(x\mid I_t)$ is a number hence $E(E(x\mid I_t)\mid\omega_t)=E(x\mid I_t)$ while $E(x\mid \omega_t)$ is a random variable, hence these cannot coincide in general, simply for definitional issues. Life is hard.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the question asked is the following:

> Let $X$ denote an integrable random variable defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$, $\mathcal G$ a sub-sigma-algebra of $\mathcal F$ and $A\in\mathcal  G$ an event of positive probability, then $$E(E(X\mid \mathcal G)\mid A)=E(X\mid A).$$

To prove this, let $Y=E(X\mid \mathcal G)$, then $$E(Y\mid A)=\frac{E(Y\mathbf 1_A)}{P(A)},\qquad E(X\mid A)=\frac{E(X\mathbf 1_A)}{P(A)},$$ hence it suffices to show that $$E(Y\mathbf 1_A)=E(X\mathbf 1_A).$$
But the fact that this last identity holds (for every $A$ in $\mathcal G$) is (together with the fact that $Y$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable) exactly the definition of the conditional expectation $Y=E(X\mid \mathcal G)$, see [the obvious reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Formal_definition).

Answer (score -1):

Here is a possible answer, but the full answer still depends on whether $f(I_t,\omega_t) = f(I_t)$ when $\omega \in I_t$ ($\omega$ is a subset of $I_t$). If so, here's a proof in the other direction. I'm just using $E[x | I_t, \omega_t ]$ instead of $E[x |I_t]$. Of course, this could come from $f(I_t,\omega_t) = f(I_t)$.

$$E[x | I_t, \omega_t] = \sum^x x f(x|\omega_t) = \sum^x x \frac{f(x,\omega_t)}{f(\omega_t)}=\sum^x x \frac{ \sum^{I_t}f(x,I_t, \omega_t)}{f(\omega_t)}=\sum^x x \frac{ \sum^{I_t}f(x|I_t, \omega_t)f(I_t, \omega_t)}{f(\omega_t)}=\sum^{I_t}\frac{f(I_t, \omega_t)}{f(\omega_t)}\sum^x xf(x|I_t, \omega_t)=\sum^{I_t}{f(I_t |\omega_t)}E[x|I,\omega_t)]=E[E[x|I_t, \omega_t]|\omega_t]$$

Comment: How do you define $E[X| G,A]$, where $X$ is a random variable, $G$ a sigma-algebra and $A$ an event?

Comment: Yes, $I_t$ and $\omega_t$ come from sigma algebras where one is contained in the other.

Comment: The question esplains that $\omega_t\in I_t$ and now you say that $\omega_t\subseteq I_t$. Both cannot be right. Please explain (or, see my answer for a coherent answer).

Comment: This is the problem with the two sources I'm looking at and one of them may not be as precise as it should be. The notation likely should include a "for all" in front of the element symbol so that it is more general and clear that we are not simply discussing a singleton contained in a set (in which case, yes, they would both be right BTW). But I believe the original author intended it to be two sigma algebras, one contained in another, and both non-singletons, as I have clearly explained.

Comment: We are closer and closer to "not a real question".